# Updating Excel Status Bar in VBA Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro code to perform trimming for data. Below is my code:

```
Sub StatusBarExample()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Trimming..."
Dim x As Long
x = 1
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
Cells(x, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=trim(RC[-1])"
x = x + 1
Loop
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

The number of data always changes, which is why I use the `Do While` loop. With this code, I only can see a message "Trimming" without knowing the progress in percentage. Can anyone help me to improve this code?

Comment: Have a look at updating `Application.StatusBar` with `x` for one way of doing it.

Comment: Forget the loop and use `.range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup)).offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=trim(RC[-1])"` Please note that the code I've included references a worksheet defined by a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I would take this approach. I like a for loop better, and this will show you the % complete in the status bar.

```
Sub StatusBarExample()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Trimming..."
Dim x As Long
Dim lRow as Long
Dim prePct as Single, newPct as Single

newPct = 0
prePct = 0
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name Goes Here")
   lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For x = 1 to lRow
      .Cells(x,2).FormulaR1C1 = "=trim(RC[-1])"
      newPct = x/lRow

      If newPct > prePct + .01
         DoEvents
         prePct = newPct
      End If

      Application.StatusBar = "Trimming..." & Format(x/lRow,"0.00%") & " Complete"
   Next x
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreeUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for the suggested edits. I made a couple changes. In the line `If newPct > prePct + .01`, you may need to change the `.01` to something else depending on the amount of data.

Comment: The status bar text make blink a lot if you keep rewriting the same thing into it. I usually store the new formatted value and only actually write it if it is different.

Comment: I suggest a few changes: 1. ScreenUpdating needs to be reset. 2. You need a DoEvents every so often or the StatusBar/Excel won't display updates if he's doing a large number of cells. Try `If Right(x, 3) = "000" Then DoEvents` (I think Right won't break on numbers with less than 3 digits, not sure)

Comment: Thanks ! I but i have question on this:

 lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If the first row is at A5, so it should be :
lRow = .Range("A5" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     ?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. The portion `.Range("A5" & .Rows.Count)` would evaluate to (in .xlsx files) `.Range("A1048581")` which is more rows than Excel holds.